# How do I create folders from names stored in a file when the folder names will include spaces?

Tags: windows-xp, mkdir

`for /f %d in (listfile) do md %d` works for contiguous folder names (even if more than 8 characters long but not if there is a space in what will be the folder name.

Answer (score 2):

`for /f %d in (listfile) do md "%d"`

Add quotes so it takes the space as a literal. Or did you want the space left out?